# Securing Nginx with SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx

I´m securing an Nginx server with SSL and I have a question. I have two virtual servers one for http listening in port 80 and the https listening in 443 like this:

```
 # HTTP server
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost; 
        ...
        # many configuration rules here for caching, etc
}
# HTTPS server
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ...
}
```

The question is, do I need to duplicate all the configuration rules that I have in the http version into my https version? Is there any way to avoid duplicate all these rules?

**UPDATE**
I´m trying to config with an include according to @ibueker answer. Looks easy but somehow is not working. Does the include need to be inside a location? Example attached:

```
 # HTTP server
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost; 
            ...
            include ./wpo
    }
```

Where wpo file is in the same path, and it´s like:

```
# Expire rules for static content
# RCM: WPO
# Images                                                   
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        root    /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpy/app;
        expires 1w;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        root  /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpy/app;
        expires 1w;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
        root   /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpy/app;
        expires -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in another file and include them for both server blocks.

```
include /path/to/file;
```